# Print reverse of a string using recursion

Tags: recursion

This code works:

```
 void reverse(char *str)
{
   if(*str) 
   {
   reverse(str+1);
   printf("%c", *str);
  }
}
```

But, if i change reverse(str+1) with reverse(++str), it doesn't print first character.

In: Geeks

Out: skee
I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're altering the pointer given to you in the very first call of the method, so when it finally gets around to printing itself out and completing the execution, the index has already been incremented to the second character.

In the first case, str+1, str isn't being modified at all, so the very last printf just prints the first character.

Keep in mind that the prefix and postfix ++ actually change the value of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

`++str` increments first then prints, you need `str++`

Comment: Hm, reverse(str++) will go infinitly or make seg. fault. Because next function gets only str, str that is incremented stays in previous funcstion and only that function can see it.
:)

Comment: good catch, so what are you trying to accomplish? you want the the other function to get str AND append to it at the same time? In the case of ++str, the other function gets the appended value of str because you have ++ before

Comment: Actually, i just 'experimented' with str++ thing.
First time i tried to solve i did str+1. str++ looked to me  as the same thing ,so yeah, just for curiosity .
I pased exam of first level of C programming, now i am on second, just want to master the c asap. :)